# Property is set in ViewModel through Controller, but when showing it in the View it is empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following ViewModel

```
    public class ShowQuestionsViewModel
{
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategoryNumber { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionViewModel> QuestionsInCategory { get; set; }

    public ShowQuestionsViewModel()
    {
        QuestionsInCategory = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
    }
}
```

In my controller i set the properties like this (snippet):

```
ShowQuestionsViewModel sqvmsub = new ShowQuestionsViewModel();

var questionsSub = db.Question.Where(y => y.category_id == sub.category_id).ToList();

if (questionsSub != null)
{
   sqvmsub.CategoryName = sub.category_name;
   sqvm.CategoryNumber = sub.prefix;
   .....
}
```

When i try to display the Properties in my View, the CategoryNumber property is empty, even though it is set in controller (i checked by debugging)..:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.QuestionsInCategory.Count != 0)
    {
    <h3>@Html.LabelFor(y => item.CategoryName, item.CategoryName)</h3>
    <h3>@Html.LabelFor(y => item.CategoryNumber, item.CategoryNumber)</h3>
```

#### @Html.LabelFor(y => item.CategoryNumber, item.CategoryNumber)

Only displays the text "CategoryNumber"

If i try to change my controller like this:

```
sqvmsub.CategoryName = sub.prefix;
```

It displays what it is supposed to, which means there is nothing wrong with sub.prefix, but with CategoryNumber in the ShowQuestionsViewModel..

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: How are you passing the model instance from the controller action method to the view?

Comment: I have a List<ShowQuestionsViewModel> listsqvm = new List<ShowQuestionsViewModel>(); and i pass it like this: return View(listsqvm); I can post the whole method, if you want to see it

Comment: How is `@model` defined? Is it `@model IList<ShowQuestionsViewModel>`?

Comment: It is: @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.ViewModels.Question.ShowQuestionsViewModel> - You can see the View here: http://pastebin.com/CFAMyzyG - I tried changing it to IList but it is the same result :(

Comment: If i do a @Html.LabelFor(y => item.CategoryNumber, item.CategoryNumber.toString()) it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - But i am setting it in the Controller right next to CategoryName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was apparently not setting the properties correctly. I changed it to:

```
ShowQuestionsViewModel sqvm = null;

var questionsMain = db.Question.Where(y => y.category_id == s.category_id).ToList();

if (questionsMain != null)
   {
      sqvm = new ShowQuestionsViewModel() { CategoryNumber = s.prefix, 
                                            CategoryName = s.category_name };
.....
}
```

It now work. Thanks for the help.